# Hook into Parse push notification open

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to be able to access the push notification before the default Activity registered through `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback()` is launched. This is easy to do when using vanilla GCM, Amazon SNS, or Urban Airship, but Parse abstracts away too many of the details for me to see an easy way to do this. I need to access the push in order to save off some information so that my library can display a UI on behalf of the host app. If I don't save off this information prior to launching the default Activity, then I have no way of knowing if the push was handled already when I return to the Activity that handled the push originally, since Intents are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You could start the service in your `Application`: `PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this)`, then subscribe to a channel when you want. It doesn't have to be tight to an `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. Can I still target specific devices in the push if I also use a channel?

Comment: When you send a push through the dashboard, and after you select `segment`, it gives you more choices to target devices (app version,  app name etc), rather than a channel.